# Python, adding two values from data input

Tags: python, string, parsing

staright to the point:
my input:

```
d = {'Key1': [('aaaaa', '834M', '118G'),
           ('bbbbb', '216G', '220.3M')],
'Key2': [('ccccc', '790M', '162G'),
           ('ddddd', '203G', '34.8G'),
           ('eeeee', '126M', '112G')],
'Key3': [('fffff', '921G', '30.8M'),
           ('ggggg', '235G', '2.63G')]}
```

I have this so far and it works but only for G (Gb) values:

```
for p, vl in pools.items(): 
    alloc = ('{}G'.format(round(sum([float(j[1].split('G')[0]) for j in vl]))))
    free = ('{}G'.format(round(sum([float(j[2].split('G')[0]) for j in vl]))))


I need to add values accordingly: 
from key1 aaaaa value 834M + 
from key1 bbbbb value 216G
then 
from key1 aaaaa value 118G +
from key1 bbbbb value 220.3M 
and so on for every key
so the output will look like this:

 216.8G 118.2G
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I'll refactor this a bit to make the lines stay within 80 characters long and to improve readability:

```
def split(j, i):
    if 'G' in j[i]:
      return float(j[i].split('G')[0]) 
    return float(j[i].split('M')[0]) / 1000

for p, vl in pools.items(): 
    alloc = ('{}G'.format(round(sum([split(j, 1) for j in vl]))))
    free = ('{}G'.format(round(sum(split(j, 2) for j in vl]))))
```

You could also write the split function as:

```
def split(j, i):
    suffix = j[i][-1]
    value = float(j[i][:-1]) 
    return value if suffix == 'G' else value / 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you code some functions to parse your input and to create the output the way you want.

A simple example could be:

```
def toFloat(s):
    return float(s.replace("G","e9").replace("M","e6").replace("k","e3"))

def toPString(num):
    lv = math.log(num,1000)
    prefs = ['k','M','G','T']
    return "{:.1f}{}".format(num/(1000**int(lv)),prefs[int(lv)-1])
```

Then you can do:

```
for p, vl in d.items():
    alloc = toPString(sum([toFloat(l[1]) for l in vl]))
    free = toPString(sum([toFloat(l[2]) for l in vl]))
    print(p, alloc, free)
```

It gives me:

```
Key3 1.2T 2.7G
Key2 203.9G 308.8G
Key1 216.8G 118.2G
```

Hope that is what you are looking for.